# How to find out if an item was dropped

Tags: jquery

I created a form that allows drag and drop for images. So what I've done is that when a user drops an image then the 
`$("#fileuploader").on('drop', function(e)` grabs the filename and then uses the `$(this).trigger('got-dropped', [filename_list]);`
to then pass on the filename to the `saveForm()`. The problem I'm having with my code is that if I do submit a form with an image
then my form is submitted twice, one with the image and one without the image. I know that the problem I'm having is due to this

```
$('#fileuploader').on('got-dropped', function(event, files){
    saveForm(files);
});

files = '';
saveForm(files);
```

but I'm not sure on how I should go about finding out if there was a file uploaded or not. If I remove

```
files = '';
saveForm(files);
```

then I can't submit my form, because the `saveForm()` function only works if I've dropped an image, but if I keep the code then my
form is submitted twice.

Here is my full js code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var getUrl = "http://cms.test";

    $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
        url: getUrl+"/admin/includes/upload.php",
        multiple: true,
        dragDrop: true,
        showPreview: true,
        previewWidth: "100px",
        showDelete: true,
        fileName:"myfile"
    });

    $("#fileuploader").on('drop', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var files_list = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

        var filename_list = [];
        for(x = 0; x < files_list.length; x++)
        {
            var filename = files_list[x].name;
            filename_list.push(filename);
        }

        $(this).trigger('got-dropped', [filename_list]);
    });

    $('#fileuploader').on('got-dropped', function(event, files){
        saveForm(files);
    });

    files = '';
    saveForm(files);
});

function saveForm(files_list)
{
    var getUrl = "http://cms.test";

    $(".create_menu").click(function(){
        var menu_title = $('input#menu_title').val();
        var type = $("input[name='type']:checked").val();
        var main_menu_checkbox = $('input[name=main_menu]').is(':checked');
        var side_menu_checkbox = $('input[name=side_menu]').is(':checked');

        if(main_menu_checkbox == true)
        {
            var main_menu = 1;
        }else{
            var main_menu = 0;
        }

        if(side_menu_checkbox == true)
        {
            var side_menu = 1;
        }else{
            var side_menu = 0;
        }

        var files = files_list;

        var selectParentMenu = $('#selectParentMenu').val();

        var dataString = 'menu_title='+menu_title+'&type='+type+'&main_menu='+main_menu+'&side_menu='+side_menu+'&selectParentMenu='+selectParentMenu+'&files='+files;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: getUrl+'/admin/menus.php?source=add_menu',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){
                // $("#message").html("<h2>It has been submitted</h2>");
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, kindly post where do you want us to help.

Comment: I've updated my question, I hope it's better now

Comment: where is the saveForm function?

Comment: It's after the `$(document).ready()`. You will see it when you scroll down.